# docker compose rails 6 example with mailcatcher doesn´t work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, mailcatcher

I have this file "docker-compose.yml"

```
    version: '3'

    services:

    web: 
        build: .
        #command: bash -c "foreman start -f Procfile.dev-server"
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"

        volumes:
            - .:/app  

        environment:
            DATABASE_HOST: database
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: miclave
            POSTGRES_DB: myapp_development  

        links:
            - mailcatcher    

        depends_on:
            - database 
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    database:
        image: postgres 
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - .:/app   
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: miclave
            POSTGRES_DB: myapp_development

    mailcatcher:
        image: zolweb/docker-mailcatcher:latest
        ports:
            - "1025:1025" 
            - "1080:1080"
```

When I try to send an email from my ruby on rails web app I get this error:

[image]

Can anybody help me to find out what I am doing wrong?. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you can't access service through `127.0.0.1`. If your services on the same network you will able to access it by the `links` directive you passed, like change your address from `127.0.0.1` to `mailcatcher`. If your services in different networks - you can open ports on service that you need to call and then access it by machine local ip address (not the `127.0.0.1` but by the your physical/virtual machine ip address in local network)